# Custom Post Type Permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a custom post types called "Emily Davies," "Gemma Patel," and "Poppy Smythe," And I'd  like to be access its archives by going to ".../emily_davies" ".../gemma_patel" and  ".../poppy_smythe". Emily Davies works, but for some reason the last two don't. They just show 404 error. I have archive-emily_davies.php, archive-gemma_patel.php, abd archive-poppy_smythe.php.

I have this code in my functions.php, and my permalink setting is set to be '/%category%/%postname%/'

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type(){

register_post_type( 'emily_davies',
array(
'labels' => array(
     'name' => __('Emily Davies'),
     'singular_name' => __('Post'),
     'add_new' => __('Add New'),
     'add_new_item' => __('Add New Post'),
     'edit_item' => __('Edit Post'),
     'new_item' => __('New Post'),
     'all_items' => __('All Posts'),
     'view_item' => __('View Posts'),
     'search_items' => __('Search Posts'),
     'not_found' =>  __('No Posts found'),
     'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Posts found in Trash'), 
     'parent_item_colon' => '',
     'menu_name' => 'Emily Davies'
    ),
'rewrite' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'menu_position' => 5,
'query_var' => true,
'has_archive' =>true,
'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt','comments',)
 )
 ); 
$labels = array(
'name' => _x('Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name' => _( 'Category'),
'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Category' ),
'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Categories' ),
'all_items' => __( 'All Categories' ),
'parent_item' => null,
'parent_item_colon' => null,
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category' ), 
'update_item' => __( 'Update Category' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name' ),
'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Category with commas' ),
'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Categories' ),
'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used Categories' ),
'menu_name' => __( 'Categories' ),
 ); 
register_taxonomy('emily_category','emily_davies',array(
'hierarchical' => true,
'labels' => $labels,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'emily-category' ),
  ));

register_post_type( 'poppy_smythe',
array(
'labels' => array(
     'name' => __('Poppy Smythe'),
     'singular_name' => __('Post'),
     'add_new' => __('Add New'),
     'add_new_item' => __('Add New Post'),
     'edit_item' => __('Edit Post'),
     'new_item' => __('New Post'),
     'all_items' => __('All Posts'),
     'view_item' => __('View Posts'),
     'search_items' => __('Search Posts'),
     'not_found' =>  __('No Posts found'),
     'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Posts found in Trash'), 
     'parent_item_colon' => '',
     'menu_name' => 'Poppy Smythe'
    ),
'rewrite' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'menu_position' => 5,
'query_var' => true,
'has_archive' =>true,
'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt','comments',)
)
 ); 
 $labels = array(
'name' => _x('Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name' => _( 'Category'),
'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Category' ),
'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Categories' ),
'all_items' => __( 'All Categories' ),
'parent_item' => null,
'parent_item_colon' => null,
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category' ), 
'update_item' => __( 'Update Category' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name' ),
'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Category with commas' ),
'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Categories' ),
'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used Categories' ),
'menu_name' => __( 'Categories' ),
 ); 
 register_taxonomy('popy_category','poppy_smythe',array(
'hierarchical' => true,
'labels' => $labels,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'poppy-category' ),
 ));

 register_post_type( 'gemma_patel',
 array(
'labels' => array(
     'name' => __('Gemma Patel'),
     'singular_name' => __('Post'),
     'add_new' => __('Add New'),
     'add_new_item' => __('Add New Post'),
     'edit_item' => __('Edit Post'),
     'new_item' => __('New Post'),
     'all_items' => __('All Posts'),
     'view_item' => __('View Posts'),
     'search_items' => __('Search Posts'),
     'not_found' =>  __('No Posts found'),
     'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Posts found in Trash'), 
     'parent_item_colon' => '',
     'menu_name' => 'Gemma Patel'
    ),
'rewrite' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'menu_position' => 5,
'query_var' => true,
'has_archive' =>true,
'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt','comments',)
)
); 
$labels = array(
'name' => _x('Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name' => _( 'Category'),
'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Category' ),
'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Categories' ),
'all_items' => __( 'All Categories' ),
'parent_item' => null,
'parent_item_colon' => null,
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category' ), 
'update_item' => __( 'Update Category' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name' ),
'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Category with commas' ),
'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Categories' ),
'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used Categories' ),
'menu_name' => __( 'Categories' ),
); 
 register_taxonomy('gemma_category','gemma_patel',array(
'hierarchical' => true,
'labels' => $labels,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'gemma-category' ),
 ));
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried refreshing the permalinks?

Visit the permalinks page, and hit save - this SHOULD solve the issue if the CPT's are working properly in every other aspect.